# Add html after the first widget in a sidebar

Tags: widgets

Just wondering is it possible to add HTML code after the fisrt widget in a sidebar so that it would only show once and not repeat after a second or third widget is added?

This is what I have so far:

```
      if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar(array(
    'id' => 'sidebar2',
    'name' => __('Sidebar 2'),
    'description' => __('The Second sidebar (Magazine link).'),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div><div class"content">Here only once</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Register separate sidebar for the first widget and add requred HTML between sidebars in template file(s).

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('First Widget Sidebar'); ?>
<div class"content">Here only once</div>
<?php dynamic_sidebar('Other Widgets Sidebar'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a different first widget? or im getting badly what you need?!

Comment: Because I'm not sure how I would include two different widget areas in a sidebar?

Comment: im really not sure what is your question. But for what i realize you´ve one sidebar widget. Inside of if you can drag and drop whatever you want...you can put a "text area" at top and code your html.

Comment: It's ok I figured it out, I basicly wanted to add some code between to widgets, I thought I could be fancy and do it in functions but now I see it was easier to do it in sidebar.php. Thanks for your time.

Comment: np...glad you found a solution :D you could also edit or post a reply solution for further needs. maybe some ppl has the same issue and find your answer useful.